# Getting the character at an index Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, string

I'm trying to get the character at a specified point in a string and I am proficient in Java but am learning VB for a competition tomorrow. I am trying to get the n char in a string.. 
for example, I have string "12345" and I want the middle character from the string which is '3' in this case. currently I'm trying to use

`middle = Nums.Chars(CInt((Nums.Length / 2))+1)`

where middle is a String. It gives me a character but sometimes that character isn't even the middle character in the string. The value of middle is the middle number + 1 so I assumed it was the character code of the char ( 0 = 1, 1 = 2, 2 = 3, etc..) but that was just my theory. So I tried to change it to a String by using

`middle = Nums.Chars(CInt((Nums.Length / 2))+1) & ""`

Alas that still didn't work so now I come here. All criticism is greatly appreciated.

TL;DR I need to find the middle character in a String, in my case the string is always an integer converted to a string.

Comment: Dim middle As String = nums.Chars(nums.Length \ 2)

Comment: Doesn't work for me, that was my initial idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Function GetMiddleString(original As String) As String
    If original.Length Mod 2 <> 0 AndAlso original.Length >= 3 Then
        Return original.Substring(original.Length \ 2 + 1, 1)
    Else If orginal.Length Mod 2 = 0 AndAlso original.Length >= 3 Then
        Return original.Substring(original.Length \ 2, 1)
    End If

    Return original
End Function
```

Note: This assumes that `original` is not null (`Not Nothing`).

Comment: After tons of trial and error I discovered that CInt doesn't round down so I did `middle = pali.Substring(Math.Floor(pali.Length / 2), 1)` and it seems to work for any size string, thanks though. I already had a `If pali.Length Mod 2 <> 0` check also

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is Mid() function to get the middle or the index of the middle char.

Comment: There was a comment that used the mid and it worked for "123" but not "12435" and it did work for "1234567"